# Quartz Core interfering with running unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, quartz-graphics

I'm attempting trying out the new unit testing in Xcode 4.4 (new to me anyway, as I used OHUnit before).

I have a few classes that I'm adding to the target, but one of them reference QuartzCore.

Obviously I've linked my unit test target to the QuartzCore framework, but it fails to run:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_CGBitmapContextCreateImage", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGImageGetBitsPerComponent", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGContextSetShadowWithColor", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Additions) imageWithShadow] in UIImage+Additions.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My build target builds successfully, but not the unit test target.

I've tried creating a blank new project, and adding one file that uses QuartzCore and I have the same problem.

Anyone else experience this or have any useful suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is your unit test target linking against your app, and injected into it?

Comment: Yeah. To figure out what is going wrong, I created a new project - with unit tests included. Ran it, it works. I then linked to QuartzCore and added one of my source files from the other project. The project compiles, but if i go to Product > Test - then it fails with the above symbol not found.

Comment: Odd, I've never had problems with QuartzCore interfering with tests. Could you put your example project up somewhere?

Comment: I'll do that, and post the details soon.

Answer (score 1):

For unit tests, you just want to test the logic of your application and try to leave out anything that has to do with UI or any extra classes/frameworks that are not necessary for the core logic of the application.  To do this you might have to move some of the logic to another file which would only be the bare minimum code that is needed.  Basically, don't import quartz core / use quartz core in unit tests.  Move the logic that you are testing into another test class.

Comment: Thanks, I know this already. I'm not testing UI, but one thing references another and it won't compile without - and i'd rather figure out why it won't compile and run the tests than start modifying all the code. The tests are not even doing anything at the moment.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that you are not supposed to add anything to ocunit that should not be there because you will have an endless amount of these errors.  You need to pull the base logic out of that file and reference the new test file, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: There is no documentation saying QuartzCore shouldn't be there. You're right in that unit tests shouldn't be testing the UI, but this is just advised practice. My error is that I'm linking against a library, and it's failing to find files i've linked against. Changing source code to make tests run is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: I'm just speaking from experience.  We have two very experienced unit testers where I work and this is what we have come to for best practice.  The reason it is best practice is because as soon as you are able to link the correct files, you might get about 20 more errors for missing files that the new ones are looking for.  My only suggestion if you don't want to do what I first said is to click on the  ocunit target and make sure all of the needed libraries are imported on that.  A lot of users add them to the project but forget to add them to the target.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Just link the whole lot, and then test the bits that I want. I don't think this is a new problem. I've had similar issues with UI code interferring with running unit tests via the xcodebuild command line in the past. I was hoping Apple had improved it in the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing framework to your test bundle.

[image]

As Kris mentioned - this may be a bad idea, but there are situations where you would actually want a core graphics for your unit tests.